# Python: Deleting control instructions from assembly code and finding dependency

Tags: python, python-2.7

Editing the question as per the comments:

I have a assembly code file with instructions arranged as below:

```
Line[1]:       | [wrr a10,a9] [add a8,a10,a3] [ld.n a8,a8,16]                                                              
Line[2]:       | [add a8,a10,a3] [ld.n a8,a8,16] [call a8]                                                                 
Line[3]:       | [ld.n a8,a8,16] [call a8] [entry a1,32]                                                                      
Line[4]:       | [call a8] [entry a1,32] [ld a8,0x1fff8910]                                                                   
Line[5]:       | [entry a1,32] [ld a8,0x1fff8910] [ext a3,a2,0,8]                                                             
Line[6]:       | [st.n a15,a1,12] [st.n a12,a1,16] [st.n a9,a1,8]                                                            
Line[7]:       | [ext a3,a2,0,8] [sll a3,a3,4] [add.n a3,a3,a8]                                                                
Line[8]:       | [sll a3,a3,4] [add.n a3,a3,a8] [ld a11,a3,128]
```

I would like to remove the control instructions described in the below list and any two subsequent load stores that appear in the instructions:

```
control_instructions = ['call', 'entry', 'j']

2_consecutive_remove = ['st', 'ld]
```

(if there is ld ld or st st appearing in 2 consecutive list items of a line, I got to remove that line)

Since call and entry appear in lines 2-5, and Line 6 has two st instructions in succession, my output should print only line 1, 7, 8

I have tried to remove the control instructions with the following code but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated

```
new_lines = [line for line in old_lines if not any(x in y for x in control_instructions for y in line )]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything thus far?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: items_to_search = ['abc', 'pqr', 'xyz']
new_list = []
for item in original_list:        
        for item2 in items_to_search:
                if item2 not in original_list:
                        new_list.append(item)

Comment: @user3769674 **edit the question** to include your code and a precise description of the problem with it (e.g. inputs and expected and actual outputs).

Comment: @jonrsharpe : Edited the question to include precise description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a file not a list so:

```
control_instructions = ['call', 'entry', 'j']
cleaned = []
consecutive_remove = ['st.n', 'ld']
with open("your_log.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not any(x in line for x in control_instructions) and sum(line.count(x) for x in consecutive_remove)  <= 1 :
            cleaned.append(line)
            print line

Line[1]: | [wrr a10,a9] [add a8,a10,a3] [ld.n a8,a8,16]

Line[7]: | [ext a3,a2,0,8] [sll a3,a3,4] [add.n a3,a3,a8]

Line[8]: | [sll a3,a3,4] [add.n a3,a3,a8] [ld a11,a3,128]
```

Comment: @Padriac Cunningham: I tried the above lines but it doesn't seem to remove the expected lines.

Comment: Post  a few lines of your original list exactly as they are represented locally

Comment: @Padriac Cunningham: I have edited the original post to include original list. It has a line[Num] followed by lists of assembly instructions.

Comment: @Padriac Cunningham: Thank you for your answer. Although the above lines of code removed the control instructions, the "line.count(x)for x in consecutive remove" returns "generator object <genexpr> at 0xXXXX". Is there a mismatch in the search pattern types in the code?

Comment: why are you returning the any line? You should not be doing anything with that.

Comment: @padriac cunningham: I was printing to see the count value.

Comment: that is a generator expression, it returns False as soon as a condition is True. You do not print it! It is an efficient way to check the condition. All you should be interested in is the result

Comment: @Padriac cunningham : My bad, Got what I was lloking for. I would also like the above lines of code to remove a ld and st.n if it appears in the same line. I presume line.count(x) counts the occurrence of the same item multiple times. Eg: if line contains a [ld ...] [st.n ...] [ld ..] my count value should return 3.

Comment: if there is more that 1 occurrence of any of the items in our consecutive_remove, we will ignore that line.

Comment: @padriac cunningham: The only additional constraint that I would like my above code to have is when the input line is of the form line[x] = [st.n a15,a1,12] [ld a12,a1,16] [add a9,a1,8] i.e two or more items appearing in the same line. Here the occurrence is only 1 but two different items appear. I would like to remove those lines too. Basically I would like to remove a line if two or more items appear from the given list, the items may be identical or different.

Comment: change second `any`  to `sum(line.count(x) for x in consecutive_remove) <= 1`

Comment: @Padriac cunningham Got it! Thanks :)